# Change memory unit sizes in Windows 10

Tags: memory

Just as the title implies, how can you change the unit sizes displayed in Windows?

Instead of displaying files like so;

`file1    3,932,160 KB`

to display as;

`file1  384 KiB`

which gives a more accurate reading of how large a file or directory is. I'm more familiar with this on Linux desktops than Windows, when I read `3,932,160 KB` it confuses me when I try to read how big that is compared to `348 KiB` and be all like *"Oh the file's only 348 KiB"* you can pretty much change the memory units in Linux just by going to the display options and change it between decimal and binary or other memory units.

Now under Windows, there's no way to change that under Folder Options, so I was wondering if there's a registry hack or modification that can be done to change the display of size units for files and directories. I know this can be done, and there should be a way to do this.

Comment: This should probably go on Super User, not the UX stack exchange

Comment: Windows does not have this feature currently.

Comment: Please do not crosspost. Flag to post to be moved. Do not also post [on other sites](http://superuser.com/questions/1027170/change-memory-size-units-in-windows-10)