# Will Windows 11's allow us to Change File Size View in File Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

Has anyone downloaded Windows 11 yet and checked if we're able to change the file size view from KB to MB, GB, etc.?

If not, I'll be downloading the iso for Window's Insider's version of Windows 11 and post if I'm there's an option to do it.
[image]

Comment: I am currently using Windows 11 preview Build 22000.51 and there is no option to change the default file size in File Explorer. This has been the norm since Windows 95, I believe, and I doubt Microsoft would bother to change it. The conclusion is [the same as Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1027170/change-memory-size-units-in-windows-10), it is not possible without a third party solution like [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/).

Comment: There is no option to change the Size unit. There are the same options as Windows 10.  Windows 11 22000.51

Comment: Be aware of the equipment requirements for Windows 11. 8th gen processor and above.